# Can Reveal.js be wrapped with SCORM?

Tags: javascript, scorm, reveal.js

I was recently asked to create a learning presentation for work and we decided on using reveal.js as the framework. We were recently informed that it would need to be compatible and wrapped with SCORM (for progress tracking purposes I am assuming). I am unfamiliar with SCORM and most of the research I have done hasn't provided me with a confident answer just yet. So I guess my question is does anyone know if Reveal.js can be integrated with SCORM? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can incorporate SCORM into a Reveal.js presentation. I would use Reveal's [`slidechanged` event](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#api) to track progress, set a bookmark, or determine if the final slide has been reached.

Integrating SCORM does not require a commercial product (sorry Brian), you can do it easily with open-source SCORM utilities such as [ADL's SCORM Wrapper](https://www.adlnet.gov/adl-research/scorm/) or my [pipwerks wrapper](https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper).

For example, if you used the pipwerks wrapper, you could do the following:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    // event.previousSlide, event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv

    pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.core.lesson_location", event.currentSlide);
    pipwerks.SCORM.save();

    if(event.currentSlide === Reveal.getTotalSlides()){
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.core.lesson_status", "completed");
        pipwerks.SCORM.quit();
    }

} );
```

I'm no Reveal.js expert, so there may be cleaner ways of doing this, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I really appreciate the example. I actually stumbled across your blog about using SCORM in HTML with pipwerks while researching this question, and had it booked marked for reference.

Comment: NP, happy to help. Note to self: I really need to update the examples on that site :)

Comment: I never said it required a commercial product, I said we had one to make it easy, and I even indicated that it was a plug.

Comment: I said sorry because (by your own admission) you had just plugged your product and I was countering with open-source. No offense meant, I am very familiar with Rustici Software and often recommend SCORM Cloud to folks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a glance at reveal.js, an overall understanding of JavaScript, and SCORM expertise I believe the answer is, yes. Essentially your presentation would need to be combined with the appropriate SCORM manifest file(s), and the various SCORM JavaScript API calls would need to be made to record the progress, result, etc. reveal.js appears to expose hooks that would make this possible.

Shameless plug: We have a product that can be used to easily add this support, see [SCORM Driver](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-driver/). Contact us at info@scorm.com.

Comment: I figured it was possible based on the reveal.js API, but I wanted to be sure before going that route. Thanks for taking the time to respond!